# Table Pagination: Won't let me edit cell values after page 1

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I am attempting to implement pagination as part of my table. I have gotten the table to create pages and be able to iterate through the table one page at a time depending on what was chosen for the rows per page. The purpose of the whole page is to have fields to add, edit, and delete data in the table.

However, my issue is I can only edit the data on page 1, and not any other page. I can delete, and add just not edit. Furthermore, if I am on another page, say page 2, and try to edit, nothing happens on that page, but whatever the last keystroke I make, will appear on page 1 in the row that is relatively the same. I just don't know why the editabiliy on each subsequent page is broken. I have even set the readOnly parameter of my table cell to permanantly writeable, but still only effects page 1.

Here is a snippet of the code that includes the return statement for the table itself.

```
<TableContainer component={Paper} className="narrow-table">
          <Table aria-label="simple table">
            <TableBody>
              <TableRow>
                {inputHeader.map((header, cellIndex) => {
                  if (
                    header !== "id" &&
                    header !== "collectDT" &&
                    header !== "upperLimit" &&
                    header !== "lowerLimit"
                  ) {
                    // Exclude "id" header
                    return (
                      <TableCell align="center" key={cellIndex} className="bold-header">
                        {header}
                      </TableCell>
                    );
                  }
                  return null;
                })}
                {isEditing ? (
                  <TableCell align="center" className="bold-header">
                    Actions
                  </TableCell>
                ) : null}
              </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
            <TableBody>
              {visibleRows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
                <TableRow key={rowIndex}>
                  {inputHeader.map((header, cellIndex) => {
                    if (
                      header !== "id" &&
                      header !== "collectDT" &&
                      header !== "upperLimit" &&
                      header !== "lowerLimit"
                    ) {
                      // Exclude "id" data
                      return (
                        <TableCell align="center" key={cellIndex}>
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            value={row[header]}
                            onChange={(event) => handleCellChange(event, rowIndex, header)}
                            readOnly={!isEditable} // Attempted readOnly={false} same result 
                          />
                        </TableCell>
                      );
                    }
                    return null;
                  })}
                  {isEditing ? (
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      <Button onClick={() => handleSaveRow(rowIndex+(page*rowsPerPage))}>Save</Button>
                    </TableCell>
                  ) : <TableCell align="center">
                  <IconButton onClick={() => handleDeleteRow(rowIndex+(page*rowsPerPage))} color="secondary">
                    <DeleteIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </TableCell>}
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
          <TablePagination
            rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100]} // You can customize the number of rows per page options
            component="div"
            count={inputData.length} // Total number of rows in your data
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            page={page}
            onPageChange={(event, newPage) => setPage(newPage)}
            onRowsPerPageChange={(event) => {
              setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
              setPage(0); // Reset to the first page when rows per page changes
            }}
          />
        </TableContainer>
```

There is also a button outside the code that is to toggles the isEditable between true and false. It starts as false.

I know my other parts of the code are functioning properly, its just this ability to edit the table cells on pages greater than 1.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Hope I am just missing something small!